How to base64 encode/decode accents characters
I am trying to base64 encode a string which contains accent characters.
echo FILE_DATE.Ç | iconv  -t utf-8 | base64

But it is giving error
iconv: (stdin):1:10: cannot convert

locale outputs:
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=


Works for me. In any case, the error message seems to point to the ., not the accented character. The data is already in UTF-8. If I echo the text to a file, file foo64 says foo64: UTF-8 Unicode text, and iconv  -t utf-8 has no changes to make. What Locale are you in ? base64 says : RklMRV9EQVRFLsOHCg== and base64 -d gets back the original.

When i echo the data to file and did file text.txt it is saying text.txt: ASCII text , and while decoding it says base64: invalid input

LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
locale output

LC_ALL=  overrides all of the preceding settings, and is itself invalid. Just set one external variable: export LC_ALL="C".

It helps if you show the actual data and messages, not just describe it. You can use od -t x1ac to show the exact data.

@Paul_Pedant locale will output LC_ALL= if the LC_ALL environment variable is empty or not set. However here, the double quotes around the other settings means the setting are implied, which is weird as both LANG and LC_ALL are unset which would imply C.UTF-8 is the default locale on the system which would be unexpected as that's meant to be the POSIX / C locale instead.

What's likely here is that you're in a UTF-8 locale but your terminal or terminal emulator is using a charset other than UTF-8.
To get that particular error, you must have the iconv from GNU libiconv as opposed to the one from GNU libc, and that Ç can't be encoded as 0xC7 as it is in a lot of single-byte encodings that have that character or you'd get iconv: (stdin):1:10: incomplete character or shift sequence instead.
I'd bet for IBM850 aka CP850 as that's still found on Microsoft Windows (and IIRC it's even the default in the "console" of English flavours of Windows believe it or not). In that charset, Ç is encoded as byte 0x80 (0200 in octal).
To confirm whether that's the case, enter:
printf %s 'Ç' | od -An -vto1

Which if I'm right should output 200.
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ printf 'FILE_DATE.\200' | iconv -t utf-8
FILE_DATE.
iconv: (stdin):1:10: cannot convert

Your locale uses UTF-8, so expects characters encoded in UTF-8. That iconv -t utf-8 would be a no-op as it's encoding from the locale's charmap (which is UTF-8) to UTF-8, except it still tries to decode that input expecting it to be UTF-8 encoded. But that 0x80 byte from that IBM850-encoded Ç is invalid in UTF-8, hence the error.
Here you'd want to fix your terminal emulator's encoding to UTF-8 (if it's indeed Microsoft Windows console, then maybe https://superuser.com/q/269818 is relevant) so it matches that of the locale. Then, when you type Ç, it would send the two bytes 0xc3 0x87 instead of 0xc7.
Then you'd just do:
printf %s 'FILE_DATE.Ç' | base64

To get the base64 encoding of the UTF-8 encoding of that string.
If you cannot change the encoding of your terminal, and you know which it is (here maybe IBM850 if that's Microsoft Windows), then:
printf %s 'FILE_DATE.Ç' | iconv -f IBM850 | base64

Would again give you the base64 encoding of the UTF-8 encoding of that string.

Understand that base64 does not deal with characters. It deals with bytes. It has absolutely no interaction with UTF-8 or any other locale. It can encode arbitrary bytes (e.g. an executable ELF file, a .JPG, a .MOV, ...) into bytes that will be in the range A-Z a-z 0-9 + /. (It pads the output with = to compensate for inputs that are not a multiple of three bytes.)
Specifically, base64 encoding splits each three (consecutive) 8-bit bytes into four 6-bit values, and then encodes each 6-bit with the appropriate plain character in the list above. So the input can be any 8-bit value, and the output is guaranteed to be plain ASCII text with no extended characters. This process is 100% reversible and lossless.
All this was originally designed to transmit binary data via  email and RS232 protocols which were only designed to convey plain text, and would freak out if the user data had any control characters.
Try this on your system.
$ echo FILE_DATE.Ç > foo1
$ od -t x1ac foo1
0000000  46  49  4c  45  5f  44  41  54  45  2e  c3  87  0a
          F   I   L   E   _   D   A   T   E   .   C bel  nl
          F   I   L   E   _   D   A   T   E   . 303 207  \n
0000015
$ #.. Note the accented character is UTF-8 octal 303 207.
$ base64 foo1 > foo2
$ od -t x1ac foo2
0000000  52  6b  6c  4d  52  56  39  45  51  56  52  46  4c  73  4f  48
          R   k   l   M   R   V   9   E   Q   V   R   F   L   s   O   H
          R   k   l   M   R   V   9   E   Q   V   R   F   L   s   O   H
0000020  43  67  3d  3d  0a
          C   g   =   =  nl
          C   g   =   =  \n
0000025
$ cat foo2
RklMRV9EQVRFLsOHCg==
$ base64 -d foo2 > foo3
$ cat foo3
FILE_DATE.Ç
$ od -t x1ac foo3
0000000  46  49  4c  45  5f  44  41  54  45  2e  c3  87  0a
          F   I   L   E   _   D   A   T   E   .   C bel  nl
          F   I   L   E   _   D   A   T   E   . 303 207  \n
0000015
$ iconv -t utf-8 foo1 > foo4
$ #.. No error given.
$ od -t x1ac foo4
0000000  46  49  4c  45  5f  44  41  54  45  2e  c3  87  0a
          F   I   L   E   _   D   A   T   E   .   C bel  nl
          F   I   L   E   _   D   A   T   E   . 303 207  \n
0000015
$ #.. iconv makes no changes, and shows no error.
$ echo FILE_DATE.Ç | iconv  -t utf-8 | base64 > foo5
$ #.. Your original pipeline, no error.
$ cmp foo2 foo5
$ #.. Shows no difference in the base64 versions.
$ cat foo5
RklMRV9EQVRFLsOHCg==
$ file foo{1..5}
foo1: UTF-8 Unicode text
foo2: ASCII text
foo3: UTF-8 Unicode text
foo4: UTF-8 Unicode text
foo5: ASCII text
$ 

